# Azure MFA login issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I have an Azure subscription. I'm the only one who uses this subscription. I had enabled MFA using Microsoft authenticator app, however I lost my phone on which it was installed. What options are available to login to the subscription again?

Answer (score 0):

MFA is not bound to an Azure Subscription but to the Azure Active Directory that is linked to your Subscription. I hope you have entered additional MFA options like phone or email.

Checkout [Common problems and solutions with two-factor verification and your work or school account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-troubleshoot) for further information.

Comment: No additional options are popping up - it is giving me the only option to use the Authenticator app. What you said is right - the problem here is to login to the directory to access the resources in the subscription.